# 406 error while retrieving the details in REST and hibernate

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, rest

I am trying to fetch the details of countries in XML using REST and hibernate. But when hitting the URL below is the error I get. I have set the header accepts in the request correctly to xml.

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating 
responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request 
"accept" headers.
```

CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCountries", method = 
RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/xml",
    headers = "Accept=application/xml")
public List<Country> getCountries() throws CustomerNotFoundException{

List<Country> listOfCountries = countryService.getAllCountries();
return listOfCountries;
}
```

MODEL

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "COUNTRY")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRY")
public class Country{

@XmlAttribute
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;

@XmlElement
@Column(name="countryName")
String countryName; 

@XmlElement
@Column(name="population")
long population;

public Country() {
super();
}
```

SERVICE

```
@Transactional
public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
    return countryDao.getAllCountries();
}
```

DAO

```
public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Country> countryList = session.createQuery("from Country").list();
    return countryList;
}
```

Can someone please help..

Comment: Do you have `Jackson` in your dependencies ?

Comment: @Thomas yes i have jackson in dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spring recommended `jackson-dataformat-xml` library in `pom.xml`. It will do automatic XML transformation for you as soon as JAXB library (which is inbuilt in JDK >= 1.6) is present, even without XML annotations. However, you can use `@JacksonXml..` annotations to given desired structure to your xml.

To achieve the desired result here, I will create a wrapper class and update my controller as below:

```
//pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>

//wrapper class
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "countries")
@Data //lombok
@AllArgsConstructor //lombok
public class Countries {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "country")
    private List<Country> countries;

}

//controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object getCountries() throws CustomerNotFoundException{
 return new Countries(countryService.getAllCountries());
}
```

**NOTE:** XML Wrapper class is not required here. Spring will just do fine with the default array transformation using `<List><Items>`, but its recommended to shape your XML as per desired structure.

Comment: Isnt there any other way to perform this?

Comment: I have updated my solution with more elegant way to achieve the result.

Comment: Did it resolve you query ? Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).